# Return top 1 record based on a condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table and records
[image: CUST_ITEMS_TBL]

How do I return all record and top 1 record where CUSTID appears more than once.

The result should like like

```
CUSTID  ORDERID  ORDERDATE ITEMPRICE
50         1      5/10/2019   10
150        2      5/10/2019   11
51         3      5/10/2019   50
```

Distinct CUSTID isn't working as I need to display all the columns.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you define "top 1 record"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you need `row_number()`

```
select a.* from 
(select *,row_number()over(partition by custid order by itemprice desc)rn
from table_name
) a where a.rn=1
```